# Angular 2+ dynamic value with in ngFor tag

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have ngFor loop with attribute disable true on some element and the value come from array which ngFor is running. But I can only get that value inside ngFor tag but not on its own. Here is the sample code

```
<div ngFor="link in links.linkArr" disable='link.disbleLink'> //can't get the value here
 <div>
  {{link.disbleLink}} // works here
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have written a complete wrong syntax of [ngFor](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#showing-an-array-property-with-ngfor). Please go through the docs

```
<div *ngFor="let link of links.linkArr" [attr.disabled]="link.disbleLink">
   <div>
       {{link.disbleLink}}
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amit are you talking about disable vs disabled? then its my typo or something else. I don't see anything different in doc that I am doing wrong.

Comment: Where is let, of, * in your ngFor?

Comment: Ok, you cannot say incorrectly typed answer as, it works. That would confuse future readers coming over here

Answer (score 1):

For binding dynamic variable in html and use angular you have two way: 
1st: [disable]="variableName".
2nd: disable="{{variableName}}".
But another important thing is that disable attribute is not available on div tag!
https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngFor="link in links.linkArr" [attr.disable]="link.disbleLink">
   <div>
       {{link.disbleLink}}
   </div>
</div>
```

or you can just use brackets :

```
<div *ngFor="link in links.linkArr" disable="{{link.disbleLink}}">
   <div>
       {{link.disbleLink}}
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still wondering how is that working for you guys with a wrong syntax?